# How to use @DataProvider in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package com.xchanging.selenium.testcases.testng;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.CaptureScreenShot;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.ClearText;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.ClickEvent;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.GlobalVariables;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.ReadRows;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.SelectCheckBox;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.SelectDropDown;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.Text;
import com.xchanging.selenium.utility.VerifyText;

public class RegisterAccount extends GlobalVariables {

    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public static void register() throws IOException {
        ClickEvent.clickAt("createAccount_xpath");
        Text.enterText("username_name", "username");
        Text.enterText("password_name", "machans");
        Text.enterText("confirmPassword_name", "machans");
        ClickEvent.clickAt("securityquestion_name");
        SelectDropDown.select("securityquestion_name", "petname");
        Text.enterText("securityanswer_xpath", "vsbhss");
        Text.enterText("fullName_name", "Chandrasekaran");
        Text.enterText("email_name", "xx@gmail.com");
        ClearText.clear("dob_name");
        Text.enterText("dob_name", "11/11/1982");
        SelectDropDown.select("gender_name", 1);
        SelectDropDown.select("marital_name", 1);
        SelectDropDown.select("country_name", "India");
        SelectCheckBox.selectchkbox("checkbox_xpath");
        ClickEvent.clickAt("register_xpath");
        VerifyText.verify("Congratulations.. You have registered successfully");
        VerifyText.verify("Login now");
        CaptureScreenShot.screenshot("Registration_Successful");
        ClickEvent.clickAt("closebutton_xpath");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public ArrayList<HashMap> getData() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<HashMap> table = ReadRows.readExcel("Sheet1");
        return table;
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to use this DataProvider and get values from xls and have to use it in my @Test Part.

Can any one help out???

If I use, this way it is working fine..

```
ArrayList<HashMap> table = ReadRows.readExcel("Sheet1");
table.get(0).get("email")
```

But I wanted to use @DataProvider..

Answer (score 0):

Some How managed..

```
@Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public static void register(ArrayList<HashMap> table) throws IOException {


}
```

This solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `dataProvider` annotation. The annotated method must return an `Object[][]` where each Object[] can be assigned the parameter list of the test method.

You can try something like this:

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData() throws IOException {
    Object[][] data = new Object[3][2] // based on the size of your excel rows & cols.
    // Write the code to read data from excel and store.
    data[][] = //your Code. 
    return data;
}
```

And your test method can use the data.

```
//Lets say your Object[][] data returns 2 arguments.
@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void testMethod(firstArgument, secondArgument){
    // your code to use the arguments supplied by data.
}
```

Comment: I have this method ReadRows.readExcel("Sheet1"); to retrive the excel sheet.. Can i some logic to take the values from this ??

Comment: I have already used this logic and I am able to retrive the data using ReadRows.readExcel("Sheet1").. ONLY thing is how to customize to use it in DataProvider

Comment: You need to customize your code such that it returns a two dimensional array of data i.e (rows & cols).